# ASCII art smoke wisp generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, ascii-art

I've written a Python function that generates a smoke wisp/genie-tail shape using all 26 (and only 26) letters of the alphabet. Here are some examples of the kind of ASCII art I'm trying to produce:

```
 v  g j p b n m a             
i h  u t                      
 f  q k                       
       s d c                  
            z o r             
                  w           
                   y          
                  x           
                l             
              e
```

```
                 l i k e w  s 
                        f m  y
                  x p a  j    
            t b o             
       h d v                  
      c n                     
       g r                    
           q                  
              z               
                u
```

I used a lot of mathematical operations to produce it: sin, exp, pow.

Please tell me what you think of the code as I've written it and my solution choices. I suspect I could have solved the problem using a less mathematically-intensive solution, that might be more performant.

```py
import functools
import math
import random

from string import ascii_lowercase


def bell(x, mean, stddev):
    r'''Gaussian bell curve shape with highest point at (mean, 1)

    Instead of a valid PDF, the shape of the bell curve is such that P(E(bell)) = P(mean) is normalised across all lines; the
    middle of the bottom lines of the wisp shouldn't be guaranteed to have a letter.
    '''
    max_y = 1
    return max_y * math.exp(-0.5 * (x - mean) ** 2 / stddev ** 2)


def calc_stddev(row_number, height, widest_value, narrowest_value, concavity):
    r'''Generate a stddev suitable for distributing the letters of one row of the wisp.

    The topmost rows should have a much less concentrated spread of letters than the bottom rows, which
    should be tightly constrained around the means of those rows to look like the tail of a genie coming out
    of a lamp.

    :param concavity: between -1 and 1, a larger value means the stddev shrinks faster. 0 is linear
    '''
    right_bound = height - 1 # put the rightmost anchor point of a quadratic bezier at this x-value
    a_x, a_y = (0, widest_value) # the left anchor point of the quadratic bezier
    def straight_line_between(x0, y0, x1, y1):
        r'''Returns a function for the straight line that contains (x0, y0) and (x1, y1)'''
        return lambda x: (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) * (x - x0) + y0
    # draw a rectangle bound by the left anchor point and the right anchor point. The more distant the control point is
    # from the diagonal connecting those vertices, the more warped the shape of the bezier will be. If the control point
    # is on that diagonal, then the bezier will be the diagonal itself. So put the control point on the other diagonal at
    # a distance away determined by the concavity
    control_point_x = right_bound/2 - concavity * right_bound / 2
    control_point_y = straight_line_between(0, narrowest_value, right_bound, widest_value)(control_point_x)
    b_x, b_y = (control_point_x, control_point_y) # the control point of the bezier
    c_x, c_y = (right_bound, narrowest_value) # the right anchor of the bezier
    x = row_number # return the y-value of the constructed bezier for the requested input
    t = (a_x-b_x + math.sqrt((a_x - b_x)**2-(a_x-x)*(a_x-2*b_x+c_x))) / (a_x - 2*b_x + c_x) # solve for t of the bezier curve at x
    y = a_y*(1-t)**2 + 2*b_y*t*(1-t)+c_y*t**2 # what is the y-value of the bezier curve at x (using t just solved)
    return y


def calc_mean(row_number, height, max_offset, funnel_factor, wavelength, seed):
    r'''Generate a mean according to a formula that will produce a sinuous smoke wisp shape.

    :param height: the total height in rows that the wisp will be
    :param max_offset: how horizontally far from 0 the widest point of inflection should be
    :param funnel_factor: a number 0 to 1, how much narrower the curves at the base of the wisp should be than the top
    :param wavelength: how much approximate distance (in terms of row_number) should there be between same-sided points of inflection
    :param seed: seed for the random number generator used to make the shape of the wisp different in different game instances
    :returns: the horizontal offset from the middle of the mistakes cloud that this row should be drawn at
    '''
    rand = random.Random()
    rand.seed(seed)
    funneling_factor = math.exp(math.log(funnel_factor)/height * row_number)
    translated_row_number = row_number + rand.randint(0, wavelength) # the offset should start according to RNG
    transformed_row_number = math.pi * 2 / wavelength * translated_row_number # additionally scale to satisfy wavelength
    return max_offset * funneling_factor * math.sin(transformed_row_number)


@functools.cache
def generate_wisp(height: int, seed: int) -> str:
    r'''Generate a 2D scattering of the alphabet in a grid according to a seeded random shape.

    At the moment, I'm going for a wisp-of-smoke/genie shape:
        #  # # #  #
      #   #
            # #  
         # #
      #
       #
    The method implemented is to align normal distributions horizontally with the middle of the smoke on each row
    according to some random sinusoid, and then placing the letters by weighted chance according to that distribution.

    :param height: the number of lines of output. The wisp will try to span all the lines
    :param seed: seed for the random number generator, so repeated calls can have predictable results
    '''
    rand = random.Random()
    rand.seed(seed)
    distribution = []
    noise = 8e-3 # each cell in the distribution gets noise% uniform randomisation
    funnel_factor = 0.2 # ratio of the amplitudes of the curves of the bottom of the wisp and the top
    concavity = 1 # how quickly the width of the wisp should narrow
    width = height * 3 # width of the 2D grid of characters that will be returned
    wavelength = height # in number of rows
    amplitude = width / 2 # the greatest distance of the curve from 0
    widest_stddev = height
    narrowest_stddev = height / 10
    for row_number in range(height): # first build a 2D distribution of likelihoods that a letter will appear in each cell
        row = []
        distribution.append(row)
        mean = calc_mean(row_number, height, amplitude, funnel_factor, wavelength, seed)
        stddev = calc_stddev(row_number, height, widest_stddev, narrowest_stddev, concavity)
        for x in range(-width // 2 + 1, width // 2 + 1):
            row.append(bell(x, mean, stddev) * rand.uniform(1-noise, 1+noise))
    grid = [[' ' for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)] # the grid of decided letter positions
    letters = rand.sample(ascii_lowercase, len(ascii_lowercase)) # the order of letters in the wisp should also be random
    while letters:
        # get the largest value from the distribution, place the letter there, then set adjacent probabilities in the distribution to zero
        flat_distribution = [p for row in distribution for p in row]
        flat_index = flat_distribution.index(max(flat_distribution))
        expected_row = flat_index // width
        expected_col = flat_index % width
        grid[expected_row][expected_col] = letters.pop()
        distribution[expected_row][expected_col] = 0 # stop future letters being placed here
        if expected_row > 0: # no vertical adjacency
            distribution[expected_row - 1][expected_col] = 0
        if expected_row < height - 1:
            distribution[expected_row + 1][expected_col] = 0
        if expected_col > 0: # no horizonal adjacency
            distribution[expected_row][expected_col - 1] = 0
        if expected_col < width - 1:
            distribution[expected_row][expected_col + 1] = 0
    return '\n'.join([''.join(line) for line in grid])
```

Test it out with

```py
print(generate_wisp(height, random_seed))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is well documented, original and seems to work the way the want it which is great. I do not quite understand everything but here are a few comments about random details anyway.

**divmod**

There's is a builtin called [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) which does exactly what you need to rewrite:

```
    expected_row = flat_index // width
    expected_col = flat_index % width
```

as

```
    expected_row, expected_col = divmod(flat_index, width)
```

**looping over letters**

Popping elements from `letters.pop()` to iterate over its elements is a bit unconventional and not that efficient. You could use a simple `for` loop here.

```
for letter in letters:
    (...)
    grid[expected_row][expected_col] = letter
```

**alphabet**

Having explicit references to `ascii_lowercase` in the body of `generate_wisp` is quite surprising. My suggestion would be to make this a parameter.

```
def generate_wisp(height: int, seed: int, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase) -> str:
    (...)
    for letter in random.sample(alphabet, len(alphabet)):  # Take letters in random order
```

**seed**

I may be missing something entirely (for examples with the cache) but I find it somewhat surprising to have the seed propagated through the different functions.

I would have written

```
random.seed(42) # or random.seed(None)
print(generate_wisp(height=25))
```

and then not mention seed anywhere.

**mathematical expressions**

Your code contains references to various formulas that I do not quite know.
However, one of the formula that I could understand was written in a way which was hard for me to grasp. This may be a personal preference but sometimes a little reordering can go a long way. For me, this:

```
    return lambda x: y0 + (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
```

is clearer than:

```
    return lambda x: (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0) * (x - x0) + y0
```

because I easily so what it the divisor and how the `x` value gets used.

The same logic applies to:

```
funneling_factor = math.exp(math.log(funnel_factor) * row_number/height)
```

and

```
transformed_row_number = 2 * math.pi * translated_row_number/ wavelength # additionally scale to satisfy wavelength
```

I suspect other mathematical expressions could benefit from being written in a small dedicated function. This may also remove the need for places where we just give the variables a better (?) name to apply such or such a mathematical function.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think it's better to seed `random` directly, instead of passing a seed to the functions? I feel like passing the random seed as an argument is functionally purer, and the function signature can't guarantee that global `random` is what it is using (there might be the consideration of concurrency too). Also, it's a problem you can't quite understand everything! What do you think is currently inhibiting ease of understanding? Could I do anything in addition to writing dedicated functions to remedy that?

Comment: For the random seed, I may be biased because I've never seen/used it that way. It makes for a "purer" function but I'm not 100% sure if this is a desirable behavior for a function handling randomness. A "get_random_number" taking a seed as a parameter would look very suspicious to me. As for my understanding, I'm definitly missing some mathematical background but maybe additional references to the concepts used could be useful.